# comparing DataGridView Columns in a Loop

Tags: vb.net

I import data from Excel file and I need to concatenate string values from 2 columns; If they are different, put both values in the last Column and change the color of the string. I can collect the rows which shows in DataGridView, But I am not sure where to compare the columns in each rows and how to compare them.

I have tried 2 loops like this to loop through rows and columns;

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvTest.Rows

        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dgvTest.Columns
```

```
  Do While Not xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1).value = Nothing
            Dim poid As Integer
            Dim poid2 As Integer






                Dim row As String() = New String() {xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 2).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 3).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 4).value,
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 5).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 7).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 9).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 10).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 11).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 12).value, xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 17).value}





                dgvTest.Rows.Add(row)




                i += 1

        Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get your started.

```
    For Each DgvRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If DgvRow.Cells("Column1").Value.ToString <> DgvRow.Cells("Column2").Value.ToString Then
            DgvRow.Cells("Column3").Value = DgvRow.Cells("Column1").Value.ToString & DgvRow.Cells("Column2").Value.ToString
            DgvRow.Cells("Column3").Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
```